# sdcard on the eclipse not showing in emulator (Gingerbread)

Tags: android, eclipse, sd-card

I am having some difficulties setting up the virtual (emulated) sdcard in Eclipse.  The target API is 2.3.3 (Gingerbread).

I have read and followed [this article](http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/) (Referred to me by a member here).

This is where the problems start - I have already made a sdcard.img file in setting up my AVD emulation.  Ihave also put in the correct file path as per step 2 (and double and triple checked the file path was correct).

The problem is when I go to the DDMS --> File Explorer, it is blank, as in totally blank - no files whatsoever are showing.

I have tried recreating the AVD emulated device, and have restarted Eclipse after each step to no avail.  Possibly a silly question (remember, this is new to me), but even though I have specified the parameters for the SD card when setting up in the AVD manager, do I still need to do step 1 (of the link above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click on your emulator name in the "Devices" tab. That will refresh connections in the "File Explorer" tab with your emulated device. If you don't see your emulator in the "Devices" window, then reset adb.

Comment: Is this in the AVD manager? If so, I see my device there and the File Manager is still blank.

Comment: No in the DDMS perspective. Go to **Window -> Show View -> Devices**. Alternatively in command-line give the command `adb devices`

Comment: Oh wait, ignore that last comment, I reread your instruction and I am at 'Devices' - and yes, it is empty.  So my next question is, how do I reset adb?  will I lose the code that I have written?

Comment: Okay, found it - but now, when I try to reset ADB - I am getting "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" in the console

Comment: Manually kill the adb.exe from Task Manager and reset it. OR go to command-line and type `adb kill-server` and then `adb devices`

Comment: if you are on Windows it is the **command-prompt** you call from - `Run -> cmd`. If you are on mac/linux, it is called **terminal**. I'm talking about the OS command-line utility. This is not present in eclipse.

Comment: hmmm the Task manager method did not work, the same error came up with repeated connection attempts.  Am going to try the commnd prompt method

Comment: it worked, thank you for that - now to solve the next mystery ( permissions of the emulated sdcard - going to do a search before asking).